# Are all physical laws and equalities dimensionally consistent?

Tags: dimensional-analysis

Once a teacher told me : If someone discovers a new physics law between three or more physical quantities, and that formula was not dimensionally correct, he can be sure that his new discovered law is wrong.

Is it a true statement? I think it's not.

I mean, the person that has discovered gravity equation, noticed that the force between two things, is related to their weights and their distance. and then he noticed that there is no way that he can make this equation, dimensionally correct:

$$\frac{ML}{T^2} = (M1)^n (M2)^m (d)^p$$

and there are no real numbers that we can replace with $n$, $m$ and $p$ to make this equation correct.

And then he just defined the unit of constant $G$, which equals to $ N m^2 kg^{-2}$. to equalize the dimensions of rhs and lhs.

Am I right?

Comment: If someone "proves" to you that 3 apples is **exactly the same thing** as 7 oranges, are you going to seriously entertain the possibility that he might be right?   What if he proves that 3 apples is exactly the same thing as 11 miles?

Comment: Of course, you can always fix up the dimensions by adding new fundamental constants, which often happens at the forefront of physics. On the other hand, if you're just doing high school physics where all the constants have been known for hundreds of years, then your teacher's advice is correct.

Comment: The answer to the question in your title is Yes. Otherwise the equality is not an equality.

Comment: Not sure why you just prepended "In the name of God" to your question. That addition does not clarify or add any useful details. Also you seem to have edited in a HTML break character, which we don't really need. I edited both out. If you want to edit your question I would suggest focusing on adding any details that could help clarify what you are asking.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is it a true statement?

Yes, any equality must be dimensionally consistent.

> And then he just defined the unit of constant $G$, which equals to $ N m^2 kg^{-2}$. to equalize the dimensions of rhs and lhs.

Yes. And in SI units the equation was incorrect without $G$.

The teacher’s statement is true, but it is also not a particularly big challenge. One can overcome it by including a dimensionful universal constant as you suggest, or more interestingly by changing to a system of units where it is consistent.

Comment: My question is: why most of physical laws don't need any 'dimensionful constants' ? All of physical equalities that I've studied till now are dimensionally correct themselves(except gravity equation). And it is even possible to predict their general form using dimension.  (e.g. W = f.d , E = m$c^2 $ , E = $1/2 mv^2$ , T = 2π$\sqrt{\frac{l}{g}}$, etc)

Comment: Another thing that bothers me is all of dimensionful constants are universal ones. like G, h , c and .... . Why are all of simple coefficients unitless? for example I've never seen a formula in this form : A = B * C  * $\frac{m}{s^2}$ where A, B and C are physical quantities and $\frac{m}{s^2}$ is a dimensionful coefficients .

Comment: @foroughm said “All of physical equalities that I've studied till now are dimensionally correct themselves”. That sounds like all you have studied is Newtonian mechanics using SI units. The SI units are designed to be dimensionally consistent in Newtonian mechanics. If you use imperial units the Newtonian equations use universal constants. And if you do electromagnetism then even SI uses inconsistent units

Comment: Incidentally both $E=mc^2$ and $T=2\pi\sqrt{\frac{\ell}{g}}$ are equations where a dimensionful constant is used ($c$ and $g$ respectively).